# Opening MXD file saved in later version of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd, save

I saved in ArcMap 10.7 an MXD file, and I can't open it in ArcMap 10.3.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Save A Copy and select the correct version.

Comment: To be clear, this has to be done from the higher release.